# Facing issues with MongoDB Bulk API while trying to upload my JSON file to MongoDB using NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I've been trying to sequentially upload my json file to MongoDB using the Bulk API. But everytime I try to do so I receive the following error "TypeError: bulk.insert is not a function"

I've  referenced the docs and my syntax looks alright. Do let me know how I can go about fixing the same.

Below is my code snippet.
productRouter.js

```
const products = require('../models/product');

productRouter.route('/bulkupload')
.get((req,res,next) => {
    var productJson = fs.readFileSync('development/mongodb-file-import.json');
    productJson = JSON.parse(productJson);
    console.log(productJson[1])
    var bulk = products.collection.initializeOrderedBulkOp();
    for (i=0; i < productJson.length; i+=1) {
        bulk.insert(productJson[i])
    }
    bulk.execute(function (errx) {
     if (errx) {
             return next(errx);
         }
     console.log('Success');
  });
})
```

**EDIT**
app.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const product = require('./models/product');
const warehouse = require('./models/warehouse');
const url = process.env.MONGODB_URL_ATLAS;
const connect = mongoose.connect(url, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
  useCreateIndex: true
});
connect.then((db) => {
  winston.info('Connected correctly to server');
}, (err) => {winston.error(err); });
```

product.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const shortId = require('shortid');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const productSchema = new Schema({
    productName: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        required: 'Please choose the product from the list!'
    },
    productUnit: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    productPricePerUnit: {
      type: Number,
      required: true
    },
    productSku: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      uppercase: 1,
      index: {
        unique: true
      },
      default: "SNS" + shortId.generate()
    }
},{
    timestamps: true
});

var products = mongoose.model('products', productSchema);

module.exports = products;
```

Comment: Are you sure your collection is like this: `products.collection.initializeOrderedBulkOp()` or like this: `products.collection('yourcollectionname').initializeOrderedBulkOp()`.

Comment: Products is my collection name!

Comment: What the example result from this `productJson`.

Comment: prodcutJson[1] is { productName: 'Aachi Sambar Powder | 1Kg',
  productUnit: 'Nos',
  productPricePerUnit: 294.64 } There are about 200 more like so.

Comment: Have you create a mongodb connection?

Comment: Yes, I have in my app.js page. I have added an edit showing the same.

Comment: Can you give me the link of your file `mongodb-file-import.json`. I want it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206970/discussion-between-uma-maheshwar-reddy-and-titus-sutio-fanpula).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do it with this code below:

```js
productRouter.route('/bulkupload')
    .get(async(req, res, next) => {
        var products = fs.readFileSync('development/mongodb-file-import.json');
        products = JSON.parse(products);
        const jobQuerys = [];

        products.forEach(p => {
            p.productSku = p.productSku ? p.productSku : "SNS" + shortId.generate();
            const product = new Product(p);
            jobQuerys.push(product.save());
        });

        const result = await Promise.all(jobQuerys);
        console.log(result);
    });
```

I hope it can help you.